# Formatting multiple CSV files in R loop

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, import

I trying to combine data from a HOBOware datalogger, every month or so we collect data and have been compiling them in excel. I'm trying to take the raw CSV files and process them in R. I'm struggling with formatting the CSV correctly in a loop

I can format each month individually via

```
Pool_xxx <- read_csv("Pool_xxx.csv", 
                           col_types = cols(`Date Time, GMT-05:00` = col_datetime(format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")), 
                           skip = 1)[,2:4]
```

But I want to create a loop that will do each CSV in the folder

I've read many posts about how to loop, but I cannot figure out where to place the column specifications

```
setwd("E:/R Hobo/Conversion test/Converted HOBO files")
mydir = "Pool 6"
myfiles = list.files(path=mydir, pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)
numfiles <- length(myfiles)     
for (numfiles in myfiles) {
      sample <- read.csv(numfiles,
                          header = FALSE,
                          sep = ",",
                          col_types = cols(`Date Time, GMT-05:00` = col_datetime(format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")),  
                          skip = 1) [,2:4]
}
```

I keep getting this back and I'm not sure where to go

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  unused argument (col_types = cols(`Date Time, GMT-05:00` = col_datetime(format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")))
```

Some people have suggested lapply but R keeps saying it's not compatible with version 3.5.3

Link to raw CSV: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SUf--PNznlNOlDkXeXYaRKuSHqa-EVZM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: In your first block, you use `read_csv` from  the `readr` package. In your loop you use `read.csv` from base R. Change the dot to an underscore.

Comment: Also, the way your  loop is set up, `sample` gets overwritten each iteration. Instead, put the data in a `list`. Before the loop, initialize `sample <- list()`. Then, in the loop, use `sample[numfiles] <- read_csv...`

Comment: One another note, you're using `numfiles` twice. You first define it as an integer with `numfiles <- length(myfiles)` and the second time as a string with a file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `readr::read_csv` in the first block of code, but in the second block of code you've switched over to `read.csv`, which is a part of `base` and has different arguments. Simply subbing in `read_csv` at `sample <- read_csv(numfiles,` should fix this problem.

I'm afraid I'm still working with R3.4.4 on a daily basis, so I don't know about this lapply issue. However, your code as written is going to overwrite sample each time you iterate over the loop -- at the end of that block, `sample` will be contain the values from the last csv read in from. Here's an alternative (leaving as much other code in place as I can): we create `sample` from the first file, then on each time through the loop, we combine it with the data read in from the next file (see `?union_all` for more on that dplyr function).

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
setwd("E:/R Hobo/Conversion test/Converted HOBO files")
mydir = "Pool 6"
myfiles = list.files(path=mydir, pattern="\\.csv$", full.names=TRUE)
# numfiles <- length(myfiles)

# You want sample to exist before the loop, so you can union the new content with the existing object
sample <- read_csv(myfiles[1],
                   col_types = cols(`Date Time, GMT-05:00` = col_datetime(format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")),  
                   skip = 1) %>% select(2:4)

for (numfiles in myfiles[-1]) { # numfiles as referenced here, and in the block below, is independent of the assignment you make above; myfiles[-1] removes the first element used above.
    sample <- union_all(sample,
                        read_csv(numfiles,
                                 col_types = cols(`Date Time, GMT-05:00` = col_datetime(format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")),  
                                 skip = 1) %>% select(2:4))
}
```

I've made a few other minor fixes and changes here. Your pattern in `list.files` was working, but that argument expects a regular expression, so this should be closer to what I think you were going for. I've removed the `header` and `sep` arguments which go to `read.csv`, not `read_csv`. Finally, I'm using `dplyr::select` in place of grabbing the columns with `[` -- `read_csv` returns a `tibble`, and select plays a bit more nicely with that; unfortunately the column names are a little hard to work with so I still selected them by index.

<strike>You didn't provide an example I can actually test, since I don't have the files you're reading from, so I couldn't test this, but it should work.</strike>

Comment: Sorry, thank you, the code you provided selects the columns twice, I've updates the post with the raw CSV. I'm in Rstudio if it makes a difference

Comment: RStudio shouldn't make much of a/any difference with a cse this simple. I'll try with the file and see what's going on here. By "selects the columns twice," do you mean that it's adding more columns, or duplicating rows/data?

Comment: It should read out columns 2-4, but I thought it did that twice (2-4 out of the 2-4). it only showed one of the columns(variables) when viewed through

Comment: I'm sorry, your code works, I didn't check to see that I didn't have dplyr installed. Thank you do much

Comment: No, happy to help! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.